# R with Lookup Table

Tags: r, time-series, cross-correlation

I have two files which contain time series in this format:

```
Tag, T1, T2, ...  Tn
Stock-1, 2, 3, ..  6
Stock-2, 3, 2, ..  7
.
.
Stock-m, 2, 1, ..  9
```

In R, for any tag (ex. Stock-x) I want to take related arrays from both files and calculate cross correlation(ccf) for them. How I can do that ?

Note: If it would be easier, I can change the file format.

Update:

I read from file into data.frames with this:

```
file1 = read.table("file1.txt", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
```

How will I reach to specific rows with Tag name such as "Stock-5" ?

Comment: You could simply read both files into two different data.frames (with `read.table()` or some such) and then access the correct rows in these two data.frames. If you need more information, if would be good if you could tell us exactly at which point in this process you have problems.

Comment: I think this is a good question, but I think it belongs more on StackOverflow than here.

Comment: Thanks, maybe a moderator can move question to SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the "Tag" from the files:

```
T1, T2, ...  Tn
Stock-1, 2, 3, ..  6
Stock-2, 3, 2, ..  7
.
.
Stock-m, 2, 1, ..  9
```

Then I was able get results with this R code:

```
file1 = read.table("file1.txt",head=TRUE,sep=",")
file2 = read.table("file2.txt",head=TRUE,sep=",")

row1 = file1["Stock-5",]
row2 = file2["Stock-5",]

vec1 = c(t(row1))
vec2 = c(t(row2))

ccf(vec1,vec2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the question might be answered with:

```
f1stock5df <- subset(file1,Tag %in% c("stock5"))

f2stock5df <- subset(file2,Tag %in% c("stock5"))

bothstocks <- rbind(f1stock5df, f2stock5df)

with(bothstocks, ccf(x,y))
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work me. Maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: It should be using rbind - but at what step does it not work?

Comment: Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : object 'Tag' not found. Anyway, I got a way, so it is not a problem. Thanks.

Comment: Oh sorry, best of luck. did you have a column named 'Tag'?